# Get current user's unique ID for WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime

I know of the [Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.aspx) class to retrieve first and last names. Is there an API to retrieve a persistent ID of the currently logged-in user? I want to roam certain user settings, but I'd hate for users to login to my app after they've already logged into their OS.

All I need is an ID that is unique to the Windows Live account of the user.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use Win8's built-in roaming folder to store user settings rather than trying to replicate that behavior on your own?

Comment: I want to store a user's scores and achievements for a game. I don't think these are settings that should roam. I'd like to be able to access these on the server for stats anyway.

Comment: You can use the Live Connect Identity http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826537.aspx. Maybe there is already a unique id, if not you can use the email as unique property.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what you want to do. If you don't want the user score to roam then why not on first load add a guid to identify the user/device combo and return that to the server?

This would also mean you weren't storing personally identifiable information on the server which a user might not expect.